# ggplot two histograms in one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I created the plot below using:

```
ggplot(data_all, aes(x = data_all$Speed, fill = data_all$Season)) + 
  theme_bw() +
  geom_histogram(position = "identity", alpha = 0.2, binwidth=0.1)
```

As you can see, the difference in the amount of data available is very large. Is there a way to look only at the distribution and not at the total data amount?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reference some of the other calculated values from stat functions using a notation that you may have seen before: `..value..`. I'm not sure the proper name for these or where you can find a list documented, but sometimes these are called "special variables" or "calculated aesthetics".

In this case, the default calculated aesthetic on the y axis for `geom_histogram()` is `..count..`.  When comparing distributions of different total *N* size, it's useful to use `..density..`.  You can access `..density..` by passing it to the `y` aesthetic directly in the `geom_histogram()` function.

First, here's an example of two histograms with vastly different sizes (similar to OP's question):

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(8675309)
df <- data.frame(
 x = c(rnorm(1000, -1, 0.5), rnorm(100000, 3, 1)),
 group = c(rep("A", 1000), rep("B", 100000))
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, fill=group)) + theme_classic() +
  geom_histogram(
    alpha=0.2, color='gray80',
    position="identity", bins=80)
```

[image]

And here's the same plot using `..density..`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, fill=group)) + theme_classic() +
  geom_histogram(
    aes(y=..density..), alpha=0.2, color='gray80',
    position="identity", bins=80)
```

[image]